# /synonyms sorting is majorly broken

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, tags, sort

I'm requesting [`/tags/synonyms` data](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/synonyms?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!*M0JhhlVm85GLL-G) in descending order by creation date, but the order is jumbled up:

[image: bad dates]

The first date is `2017-08-22` where as the second one is `2018-03-16`. The same can be observed for the 3rd and 4th entries also.

Is this a bug? or the ordering is happening on something like `last edited date of the synonym`?

Comment: Confirmed.  The sort order is not correct for any of the possible date properties.  `fromdate` and `todate` parameters are also fubar. ... Spot-checked some `creation_date`s against the [synonym info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) and at least the values are correct. It's just the sorting is borked.

Comment: @BrockAdams will i have to work around this bug? or can i expect someone from `stackexchange` team to fix it?

Comment: a1626, I can't speak for Stack Exchange, but the response to API bugs has been highly variable. ... Best guess for a workaround:  Get all 3K synonyms. Sort and store in your app.  Once a day, or so, fetch just the total (`total` filter).  If that has changed, refetch the entire list.  ... Good luck and if you get a response from SE (via another channel) let us know.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for the suggestion. That's what i've implemented as a a workaround for now.